# JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, json, string, casting

my json look like this

```
{"FROM_JID":"ff2fbe2f1e856a0c5c93616a463f7bdeef9bf7a0","TO_JID":"30df65445882e2c83783aad963ae64ca9ab6891a","TYPE_ID":"1","PLATFORM":"IOS","CONTENT":"{\"FROM_JID\":\"ff2fbe2f1e856a0c5c93616a463f7bdeef9bf7a0\",\"FROM_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"FROM_JNAME\":\"G0173A2D\",\"TO_JID\":\"30df65445882e2c83783aad963ae64ca9ab6891a\",\"TO_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"MESSAGE_ID\":\"074f36be91093e9c1490a9d9c984e15d\",\"MESSAGE_TYPE\":\"not_avt\",\"STAMP\":\"2016-01-13T10:21:03.761817Z\",\"MESSAGE\":{\"mt\":\"not_avt\",\"jid\":\"ff2fbe2f1e856a0c5c93616a463f7bdeef9bf7a0@ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\"},\"BADGE\":14,\"CONTENT-AVAILABLE\":1,\"SOUND\":\"default\"}","DEVICE_ID":"54A89FDE-0981-46D2-895B-0445AFC4B072","PUSH_ID":"37257446ea74b2e9b688407aa8a6ad94dd270a9d450f37f2bc3f6c9af5362c69","CREATE_DATE":"2016-01-13","CREATE_TIME":"10:21:03"}
```

and my code is

```
JSONParser content_parser = new JSONParser();
                        Object objMessage_Content = content_parser.parse(strContent);
                        JSONObject jsonObjectMessage_Content = (JSONObject) objMessage_Content;
                        String strMT=(String) jsonObjectMessage_Content.get("MESSAGE_TYPE");
                        String strM=(String) jsonObjectMessage_Content.get("MESSAGE");
```

i got an exception that is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

and i checked json is valid json.can some one please help.

Comment: `MESSAGE` is an object not a `String` `\"MESSAGE\":{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using gson

so first get the `MESSAGE` - this will be a JSONObject

```
JsonObject message = jsonObjectMessage_Content.getAsJsonObject("MESSAGE");
```

then you get the String `MESSAGE_TYPE`

```
message.getAsString ("MESSAGE_TYPE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
String strMT= jsonObjectMessage_Content.optString("MESSAGE_TYPE");
String strM= jsonObjectMessage_Content.optString("MESSAGE");
```